# Material thickness to withstand Pressure

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pressure, waterproofing

Let's say I have a Sphere made out of Acrylic, with a diameter `d` meters.

And I want to submerge it down in the ocean. The depth is such that it reaches up to `p` PSI.

How thick does the Sphere have to be, in order to withstand pressure of up to `p` PSI?

(I used the variables `d` and `p` so I can be given a formula that I can learn/understand instead of a raw answer.)

Comment: You need the strength of the material to start with and there are questions similar to this on this site...

Answer (score 2):

take note if you are talking about dropping to the deepest parts of the ocean the pressure can be as high as 15,000 psi.  the Yield strength of acrylic is maybe 10,000 psi.

Your wall will be very thick! You can not use most of the thin shell based formulae you might look up.

You can take an extreme view and imagine a large block of material with a tiny void. The wall hoop stress at the void wall is approximately 3/2*pressure, or over 20,000 psi. Which is to say your cavity is liable to collapse no matter how thick you make it.

Answer (score 1):

The basic formula used in analyzing *thin-walled spherical pressure vessel* is:

> stress = PD / 4t

where P is the pressure inside or outside, D is the inner diameter, and t is the wall thickness.

therefore:

> t = PD / [(allowable stress of the material) * 4]

Note that this formula is only applicable if D/t >= 10

Note also that allowable stress in acrylic is 10,000 psi @ **room temperature**. This changes when you submerge this in water, so might want to consider this too.

---

Edit:
The unit of measurement in the formula is:

For English system: stresses should be in *pounds per sq.inch (psi)* while dimensions should be in *inches (in.)*

For SI system: stresses should be in *megaPascal (MPa)*, and dimensions should be in *millimeters (mm)*

Comment: Why does temperature have to be involved in this when it's not involved in the Formula ^? On datasheets of materials (found online), when they mention how much pressure (PSI) the material can hold, at what conditions do they mean it? What temperature, thickness, shape etc.?

Also, what is the unit measurement for each variable in the formula ^?

Comment: Material tend to loose strength when they are heated or cooled. Imagine a steel bar being heated, it will lose its elasticity. Same goes when you are going to submerge in deep ocean, where temperature starts to vary @ **very large depths**. I am only saying this because room temperature is absolutely different from sea temperature. Thus, he needs to consider the case in determining the allowable stress of material. :)

Comment: Where can I find how much a material gets affected under x Degrees?

Comment: @Coto, you can find a reference here: https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=S8AkAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=ASTM+stress+temperature&source=bl&ots=NwC-k7VjXe&sig=qzNIfLQQJ7xtCc7C6ge4UVnVa4Y&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=ASTM%20stress%20temperature&f=false

Comment: BTW, how deep do you see the sphere is to be submerged?

Comment: You mean how deep I'm looking to submerge my sphere? Around a few hundred meters or less I suppose. Much less probably. But even at a depth of 11Km (Mariana Trench) the temperature is -3C. Which I suppose isn't that cold to affect the stress much.

Comment: Well, for simplicity and for theory, you can use the formula for determining the wall thickness. But for actual application, **you should consider** temperature effects. It is important to note that 10,000 psi is the stress derived from **room temperature**. I am saying it is important because freezing a material can make it brittle. There are a lot of application to this. Example is when **Dominic Toreto** of Fast and the Furious (the first scene) stole the cargo truck of gasoline. They froze the metal and with a light blow, the metal broke. This maybe is the exaggerated effect but it is real

Comment: @JemEripol why will thin wall expressions be suitable in this case?

Comment: @SolarMike, I just gave him a solution for a thin-walled vessel, because thin-walled vessels are practical solutions to submerged bodies. He can do thick-walled pressure vessel too, but that will require quite different approach. That's why I noted that I is to be used to D/t >= 10.

Comment: @JemEripol so in short, you have provided a "solution" that will not give correct results in the situation described. Why do you think the different formulae for thin and thick pressure vessels were developed ? Boilers exploded due to this...

Comment: You should provide another solution then for thick walled vessel, rather than criticizing an answer. This is not the ONLY answer. This is ONE of the answers. Provide a concrete explanation, not just giving them formula.

Comment: In fairness the OP did not specify depth.  It may be useful here to crunch some numbers and provide an estimate of depth where the sphere might be sufficiently thin.